# Is there a way to create a chrome-like tab using CSS?

Tags: css

I have been looking for a Google Chrome-like tab written using CSS but cannot find one.

I am trying to replicate the look in order to use it in a web application or a website.

Comment: Wait, what? Are you trying to put tabs inside your tab so you can tab while you tab? In other words, what are you trying to replicate? The look? The behavior? Also, how are the tabs in Chromium different from the usual tabs that have been done using CSS many times (e.g. this with different images: http://htmldog.com/examples/tabs6.html )?

Comment: @Piskvor Your second sentence is brilliant :)

Comment: @Piskvor: I was wondering if there is a way to do it without using images (as a first choice) .. just wondering if there is a way to "Redner" this using css

Comment: @user220755: As Chrome tabs are non-rectangular in the default theme, I'd say "probably not". While you could do various tricks using canvas or CSS3 effects, the easiest way to do this would be with custom images of the tab borders.

Comment: It is possible to make rounded corners in css and that's why I was asking the question if it is possible to make a chrome-like tab using css. Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

yeah its possible, with css3

Ive posted a blog about how to its a lil depthy, and sadly enouth not going to work on ie unless you use images

Edit:

Removed old reference to redeyeoperations cause its a link farm now.
This is a bit lighter version also it is up on a 3rd party site, so its less likely to be down.

http://codepen.io/jacoblwe20/pen/DxAJF

Here is the code

```js
var tabs = $('.tabs > li');

tabs.on("click", function(){
  tabs.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #efefef;
  font: .8em sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-container {
  background: #2BA6CB;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 35px;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 35px;
  max-height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px
}

ul.tabs > li.active {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #efefef;
}

ul.tabs > li.active:before {
  border-color: transparent #efefef transparent transparent;
}

ul.tabs > li.active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #efefef;
}

ul.tabs > li {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px -10px 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px 170px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px 90px;
  padding: 0 30px 0 25px;
  height: 170px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  max-width: 200px;
}

ul.tabs > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

ul.tabs > li:before,
ul.tabs > li:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.tabs > li:before {
  border-color: transparent #ddd transparent transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(48deg);
  transform: rotate(48deg);
  left: -23px;
}

ul.tabs > li:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ddd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-48deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-48deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-48deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-48deg);
  transform: rotate(-48deg);
  right: -17px;
}

/* Clear Fix took for HTML 5 Boilerlate*/

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=tab-container>
  <ul class="tabs clearfix" >
    <li>
      <a href=# >Users</a> 
    </li>
    <li class=active > 
      <a href=# >Pending Lots</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
      <a href=# >Nearby Lots</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# >Recent Lots</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class=outer-circle></div>
```

Comment: The `redeyeoperations.com` is just a link farm (or blank if you run an adblocker). `codepen.io` example looks really nice in Chrome/Chromium, but looks kinda wonky (in exactly the same way) in Firefox and Explorer (the tabs just have an odd shape -- they still work as expected).

Comment: I implemented some tabs based on this, but modified to work on Firefox and MSIE 11 on http://klingonska.org/dict/. You can also look at the unminified [SCSS file](https://github.com/zrajm/klingonska.org/blob/master/site/includes/pagetabs.scss) and [HTML file](https://github.com/zrajm/klingonska.org/blob/master/site/dict/about.html) that are available on github. (Sorry for not giving you a codepen or jsfiddle.) :/

Comment: @zrajm thank for letting me know about the link I lost that domain a while ago.

Comment: It looks so ugly in firefox browser , and i go with @zrajm , but i not looks great, any other css tricks will be appreciated

Comment: Small improvement : Assign a high z-index to the anchor tag. It tends to be covered by other elements.

Comment: @JacobLowe some explanation of what is happening would be very helpful

Comment: It would be great to have a delete button.

Answer (score 4):

I am just giving some css for getting chrome like tabs, rest its up to you to use as  you want.

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .chrome_tab {
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid grey;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 2px 2px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>


<div class='chrome_tab'>
    muhammad(peace be upon him)
</div>
```

demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/GH7d6/

Comment: its just a css tab , inside color or text and animation do according to your need

Answer (score 3):

I created [here](https://codepen.io/FeehGb/pen/BaQOrPK) tabs like google chrome stylish UI, you can find the light and dark themes in the attached pen.

```
<div class="sd-tabs" dark>
        <div class="sd-header-tabs">
            <div class="sd-group-tabs">

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-1" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-1'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-2" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-2' icon-only>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc"></div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-3" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-3'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-4" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-4'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-5" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-5'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-6" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-6'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <input class="sd-tab-radio" type="radio" tab id="rTab-7" name="tab">
                <label class='sd-tab-label' for='rTab-7'>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="whatsapp"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-whatsapp fa-w-14 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M380.9 97.1C339 55.1 283.2 32 223.9 32c-122.4 0-222 99.6-222 222 0 39.1 10.2 77.3 29.6 111L0 480l117.7-30.9c32.4 17.7 68.9 27 106.1 27h.1c122.3 0 224.1-99.6 224.1-222 0-59.3-25.2-115-67.1-157zm-157 341.6c-33.2 0-65.7-8.9-94-25.7l-6.7-4-69.8 18.3L72 359.2l-4.4-7c-18.5-29.4-28.2-63.3-28.2-98.2 0-101.7 82.8-184.5 184.6-184.5 49.3 0 95.6 19.2 130.4 54.1 34.8 34.9 56.2 81.2 56.1 130.5 0 101.8-84.9 184.6-186.6 184.6zm101.2-138.2c-5.5-2.8-32.8-16.2-37.9-18-5.1-1.9-8.8-2.8-12.5 2.8-3.7 5.6-14.3 18-17.6 21.8-3.2 3.7-6.5 4.2-12 1.4-32.6-16.3-54-29.1-75.5-66-5.7-9.8 5.7-9.1 16.3-30.3 1.8-3.7.9-6.9-.5-9.7-1.4-2.8-12.5-30.1-17.1-41.2-4.5-10.8-9.1-9.3-12.5-9.5-3.2-.2-6.9-.2-10.6-.2-3.7 0-9.7 1.4-14.8 6.9-5.1 5.6-19.4 19-19.4 46.3 0 27.3 19.9 53.7 22.6 57.4 2.8 3.7 39.1 59.7 94.8 83.8 35.2 15.2 49 16.5 66.6 13.9 10.7-1.6 32.8-13.4 37.4-26.4 4.6-13 4.6-24.1 3.2-26.4-1.3-2.5-5-3.9-10.5-6.6z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-desc">Descricao da tab bem grande para teste</div>
                    <div class="sd-tab-icon sd-tab-close">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="times" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-10 fa-2x">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M193.94 256L296.5 153.44l21.15-21.15c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31l-22.63-22.63c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L160 222.06 36.29 98.34c-3.12-3.12-8.19-3.12-11.31 0L2.34 120.97c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31L126.06 256 2.34 379.71c-3.12 3.12-3.12 8.19 0 11.31l22.63 22.63c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0L160 289.94 262.56 392.5l21.15 21.15c3.12 3.12 8.19 3.12 11.31 0l22.63-22.63c3.12-3.12 3.12-8.19 0-11.31L193.94 256z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this : 
http://codepen.io/justd/pen/dPeKEG/

Find tuto [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-chrome-like-tabs-with-bootstrap-and-angularjs) .

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import "compass";

.tab-container {
  background: #8dc8fb;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 40px;

  ul {
    &.nav-tabs {
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      line-height: 40px;
      max-height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      @include display-flex;
      padding-right: 20px;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #f7f7f7;

      $color: #c3d5e6;

      > li {
        $raduis: 28px 145px;

        margin: 5px -14px 0;
        @include border-top-left-radius($raduis);
        @include border-top-right-radius($raduis);
        padding: 0 30px 0 25px;
        height: 170px;
        background: $color;
        position: relative;
        @include box-shadow(0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
        width: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        min-width: 20px;
        border:1px solid #aaa;

        &:first-child {
          margin-left: 0;
        }

        &:last-of-type {
          margin-right: 0;
        }

        > a {
          display: block;
          max-width:100%;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #222;
          padding: 3px 7px;

          span {
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: block;
          }

          &:focus,
          &:hover {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-color: transparent;
          }

          .glyphicon-remove {
            color: #777;
            display: inline-block;
            padding:3px;
            font-size: 10px;
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top:7px;
            right: -10px;
            @include border-radius(50%);

            &:hover {
              background: #d39ea3;
              color: white;
              @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25));
              @include text-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25));
            }
          }
        }

        &.active {
          z-index: 2;
          @include background-image(linear-gradient(white, #f7f7f7 30px));

          > a {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: transparent;

            &:focus,
            &:hover {
              background-color: transparent;
              border-color: transparent;
              border-bottom-color: transparent;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      .btn {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        width: 35px;
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 35px;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        border-color: #71a0c9;
        outline: none;

        @include transform(skew(30deg));

        &.btn-default {
          background: $color;

          &:hover {
            background: #d2deeb;
          }

          &:active {
            background: #9cb5cc;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .tab-pane {
    padding: 60px 40px;
    text-align: center;

    &.active {
      border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    }
  }
}
```