# css3 before and after to create shape instead using an image

Tags: css, css-shapes

is ther a way to create a menu items like this [image: wavy image menu]

without the need to use images?
iv'e tried playing with the before and after attributes but that does not seem to work since i don't really know how to create the angles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in css

```
body{
  background : #efefef;
  font : .8em sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-container{
  background : #2BA6CB;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 35px;
}

ul.tabs{
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type : none;
  line-height : 35px;
  max-height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px
}

ul.tabs > li.active{
  z-index: 2;
  background: #efefef;
}

ul.tabs > li.active:before{
  border-color : transparent #efefef transparent transparent;
}


ul.tabs > li.active:after{
  border-color : transparent transparent transparent #efefef;
}

ul.tabs > li{
  float : right;
  margin : 5px -10px 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px 170px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px 90px;
  padding : 0 30px 0 25px;
  height: 170px;
  background: #ddd;
  position : relative;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  max-width : 200px;
}

ul.tabs > li > a{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

ul.tabs > li:before, ul.tabs > li:after{
  content : '';
  background : transparent;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  border-style : solid;
  position : absolute;
}

ul.tabs > li:before{
  border-color : transparent #ddd transparent transparent;
  -webkit-transform : rotate(48deg);
  left: -23px;
}

ul.tabs > li:after{
  border-color : transparent transparent transparent #ddd;
  -webkit-transform : rotate(-48deg);
  right: -17px;
}

/* Clear Fix took for HTML 5 Boilerlate*/

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

And add this html:

```
<div class=tab-container>
  <ul class="tabs clearfix" >
    <li>
      <a href=# >Users</a> 
    </li>
    <li class=active > 
      <a href=# >Pending Lots</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
      <a href=# >Nearby Lots</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=# >Recent Lots</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class=outer-circle></div>
```

It will result in:

[image]

Source: [Is there a way to create a chrome-like tab using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322895/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-chrome-like-tab-using-css)