# Style tab-bar like in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tabs

I'm trying to recreate Google Chrome's tab bar as accurately as possible with HTML/CSS. But it turns out to be quite a bit more complicated than I thought.

[image]

It already looks pretty similar, but I noticed several issues:

- when the tabs are resized the angles get messed up
- the z-indexing doesn't work as expected
- the hover events don't work
- where tabs overlap it looks bad
- text is not vertically centered (in Firefox it works actually)
- the tabs are lacking curves on the bottom
- the x buttons don't stick to the right

Any ideas?

I tried to look at chromes source code to see if I could find the original color/transparency/curve values, but [I couldn't find anything](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/tabs/).

Before I forget, if possible in any way, I'd like this to be more or less compatible with IE8, even if that means that the tabs can't be trapezoid shaped etc.

**EDIT2**: Rewrote the whole thing from scratch. (Credits to Ben Rhys-Lewis for the new-tab-button)
https://jsfiddle.net/p7vxzLjq/17/

```css
body {
  background: #21C256; /* green windows theme */
  /* using transparency the tabbar should automatically adjust itself to whatever color is defined here */
}
.tab-bar {
  height: 23px; /* tab height */
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none; /* disable text selection */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none; /* disable image drag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
}
.tab {
  background: #FFFFFF; /* inactive tab background color */
  opacity: 0.726; /* inactive tab transparency */
  width: 213px; /* tab width */
  //max-width: 213px; /* messes up the trapezoid angles */
  margin-left: 0px; /* tab overlap */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  /*padding-bottom: 1px;*/
  
  border-radius: 3px; /* tab curves */
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg); /* tab shape angle */
  box-shadow: 0 0 2pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* tab outline */
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 8px; /* icon left side margin */
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: -2;  /* inactive tabs are generally in the background */
}
.tab:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.tab-content {
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg); /* untransform tab content (this makes stuff blurry! :( ) */
  -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -khtml-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}
.tab-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.tab-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; /* tab text font */
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision; /* tab text improve rendering */
  font-size: 12px; /* tab text size */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000, 200px, transparent); /* make text fade at the right edge (webkit only)*/
}
.tab-close {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  right: 5px;
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/YlimbFeb56qF.png);
}
.tab-close:hover {
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/rNqZRYHpNQBr.png);
}
.active-tab {
  z-index: -1; /* active tab is in front of other tabs, but still behind the content box */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #F8F9F9); /* active tab color */
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.active-tab:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 25px; /* new-tab-button width */
  height: 14px; /* new-tab-button height */
  margin-top: 5px; /* to vertically center the new-tab-button */
  margin-left: 7px; /* margin between tabs and new-tab-button */
  box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* new-tab-button outline */
  background: #FFFFFF; /* new-tab-button color */
  opacity: 0.626; /* new-tab-button transparency */
  border-radius: 2px; /* new-tab-button curves */
  transform: skew(20deg); /* new-tab-button shape angle */
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -khtml-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
}
.new-tab:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#content {
  z-index: 1; /* the content box is always in the foreground */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F8F9F8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-bar">

  <li class="tab">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <img class="tab-icon" src="http://amazon.com/favicon.ico"/>
      <span class="tab-text">Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more</span>
      <span class="tab-close"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="tab active-tab">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <img class="tab-icon" src="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
      <span class="tab-text">Google</span>
      <span class="tab-close"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="new-tab"></li>
  
</ul>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/jcblw/pen/DxAJF what about this ?

Comment: This doesn't even look remotely like Chromes tab bar.

Comment: http://adamschwartz.co/chrome-tabs/ ?

Comment: and lot of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322895/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-chrome-like-tab-using-css

Comment: Doesn't look like Chrome tabs. At least in Firefox. I've already seen all those links..

Comment: Google JUST changed the style of the tabs in Chrome to scharp edges/corners. This problem just got a whole lot easier... :-)

Comment: For real? ...wow, what are the odds.. edit: nope, just updated to 50.0.2661.94 m and it's still the same. (Win 8.1)

Comment: On my chromebook they now have sharp corners. I expect your Windows to follow any day soon...

Comment: Is the tab bar supposed to be slightly lower?

Answer (score 4):

OK here is a fiddle of a css shape like the new tab one you want.

```
#newtab {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: #A8D5C1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2p74co0q/

For the transparency values, its hard to see from your image but I guess just trial and error. Obviously how your chrome looks is different to how mine looks because of the theme you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tab button. I already went the trial-and-error route for hours, but I just couldn't figure it out. Now that I think about it, maybe chrome is not only applying transparency, but also shifting the brightness or something like that.. At least that would explain why I couldn't get the RGB to match, just by changing the opacity value.

Comment: Yeah possibly. Why do you need it to be so exact? It looks basically there to me from the image.

Comment: Okay, the colors don't have to match the original by 100%. But there are other things than the color. Since the tabs are transparent it looks weird where they overlap. And there is a slight curve missing where the tabs touch the tab bar. And when I display text on the tabs, it gets weirdly transformed and doesn't look like the original at all.

Comment: I bet the tabs aren't transparent. As Ben says, it's tricky to know since you're using some third-party theme, but I bet it's just a washed out version of the tab bar's background color.

Answer (score 4):

Had to change many things for it to work properly. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirkurt53/w91r50wp/). Some notes on changes:

- Hover didn't work because of `pointer-events` property on tab class. You can put it under `tab-close` class or you can use *jQuery* solution for it to work in old browsers.
- I don't see any reason to use negative `z-index`. I didn't use and it seems to work.
- For `vertical-align` to work properly, you should have a constant `line-height`. Added `line-height` property to tab class and made all sub classes inherit it so that they will be aligned to middle properly. Also had to wrap images with extra divs for them to align properly.
- About the overlap, if you want a result as in Chrome tabs, you should not use opacity. No matter what you do, if you have opacity, result will look like that. You can use constant color instead.
- For bottom curve and shadow added new elements. Not sure if it is a must but it looks more like Chrome tabs.

**For it to work in IE8**

I tested it on IE8 and it did not look pleasant. Don't know where to start. Here are some thoughts:

- `vertical-align` will not work reliably. You can ditch everything with `vertical-align` and use constant `absolute` positioning. This means you cannot change tab sizes as you want and you must chose a constant one.
- You must write `filter` equivalents of all `transform` and `opacity` properties. Your css will look like the darkest place of hell.
- `border-radius` will not work. There are some dirty workarounds which I do not suggest. Same for `box-shadow`.

```css
body {
    background: #21C256;
    /* green windows theme */
    /* using transparency the tabbar should automatically adjust itself to whatever color is defined here */
}

.tab-bar {
    height: 26px;
    /* tab height */
    line-height: 26px;
    /* this is critical for vertical alligning */
    cursor: default;
    user-select: none;
    /* disable text selection */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
    z-index: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.tab-bottom-curve-left {
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit;
    opacity: inherit;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: -2px;
    z-index: 5;
    transform: rotate(-31deg);
}

.tab-bottom-curve-right {
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit;
    opacity: inherit;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -2px;
    transform: rotate(31deg);
    /* box-shadow: inherit; */
    z-index: 0;
}

.tab-icon {
    pointer-events: none;
    /* disable image drag */
}

.tab-text {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.tab {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /* inactive tab background color */
    opacity: 0.726;
    /* inactive tab transparency */
    width: 213px;
    /* tab width */
    margin-left: 0px;
    /* tab overlap */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    /*padding-bottom: 1px;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    /* tab curves */
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
    /* tab shape angle */
    box-shadow: 0 0 2pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    /* tab outline */
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 8px;
    /* icon left side margin */
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    /* inactive tabs are generally in the background */
    line-height: inherit;
    /* margin-left: -1px; */
    /* margin-right: -1px; */
    /* margin-top: -6px; */
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.tab:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.tab-content {
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    /* untransform tab content (this makes stuff blurry! :( ) */
    -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    -khtml-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
    line-height: inherit;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* position: absolute; */
}

.tab-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.tab-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    /* tab text font */
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    /* tab text improve rendering */
    font-size: 12px;
    /* tab text size */
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000, 165px, transparent);
    /* make text fade at the right edge (webkit only)*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-close {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 16px;
    line-height: inherit;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.tab-close-img {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/YlimbFeb56qF.png);
}

.tab-close-img:hover {
    background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/rNqZRYHpNQBr.png);
}

.active-tab {
    z-index: 2;
    /* active tab is in front of other tabs, but still behind the content box */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #F8F9F9);
    /* active tab color */
    /* position: relative; */
    opacity: 1;
    /* padding-bottom: 2px; */
}

.active-tab:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.new-tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25px;
    /* new-tab-button width */
    height: 14px;
    /* new-tab-button height */
    /* margin-top: 7px; */
    /* to vertically center the new-tab-button */
    margin-left: 6px;
    /* margin between tabs and new-tab-button */
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    /* new-tab-button outline */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /* new-tab-button color */
    opacity: 0.626;
    /* new-tab-button transparency */
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* new-tab-button curves */
    transform: skew(20deg);
    /* new-tab-button shape angle */
    -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    -khtml-transform: skew(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    display: inline-block;
}

.new-tab:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    /* the content box is always in the foreground */
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #F8F9F8;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.tab-bottom-shadow {
    /* width: 100%; */
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
    z-index: 5;
}

.active-tab .tab-bottom-shadow {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-bar">

        <div class="tab">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <span class="tab-icon-wrap"><img class="tab-icon" src="http://amazon.com/favicon.ico" /></span>
                <span class="tab-text">Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more</span>
                <span class="tab-close"><span class="tab-close-img"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-left"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-right"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-shadow"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <span class="tab-icon-wrap"><img class="tab-icon" src="http://youtube.com/favicon.ico" /></span>
                <span class="tab-text">YouTube</span>
                <span class="tab-close"><span class="tab-close-img"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-left"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-right"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-shadow"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab active-tab">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <span class="tab-icon-wrap"><img class="tab-icon" src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" /></span>
                <span class="tab-text">Google</span>
                <span class="tab-close"><span class="tab-close-img"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-left"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-curve-right"></div>
            <div class="tab-bottom-shadow"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="new-tab"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice! About the opacity: I don't really need opacity, I just need the tabs to automatically adjust to different color themes and opacity was the only thing I could think of.
The bottom "curve" looks more like a weird spike or something to me tbh. For IE8 it would be okay if the tabs would lack the shape and rounded corners etc as long as the thing just works and looks "okay".   
Anyways, I'm still really worried about tab resizing like in Chrome and what if a tab has no icon? http://250kb.de/u/160503/p/CsVgtTwnkKwy.png

Comment: The auto resizing is impossible with pure css. You should involve some (a lot of) javascript. You can also use javascript for tabs to adjust to different colors. Tabs look okay without icons. 

About IE8 and other things, I gave you some tips about how css works. Rest is for you to improvise. You can either make an entirely different stylesheet for IE8 or you can even make all shape and rounded corners look the same as in newer browsers. It is up to your determination and how much time are you going into invest.

Comment: Although I said auto resizing is impossible, it is somehow possible with table layout as in here https://jsfiddle.net/sirkurt53/w91r50wp/7/. Based on my experience, table layout works different in most browsers so I suggest a javascript solution.

Comment: The opacity problem could be tackled by adding `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px RGBa(255, 255, 255, 0.726);` and setting the `background-color` to that of the body in the `.tab` class. Same trick can of course be applied to `.nav:hover`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/krhLuq7w/1/.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use pure CSS? Or can you use image mapping. That way, you can create links, hover events with minimal effort, which achieve the same effect.

http://www.image-maps.com/ is a great tool to use for projects like this. You could use the polygon tool to select the buttons.

Don't worry if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Hm, I'd prefer pure CSS. But thinking about it it might not even be possible in pure CSS. I mean the transformation really messes up if the tabs are allowed to resize themselves and also due to the transformation the text becomes all blurry and since I'd like to be IE8 compatible, images would probably be a really good idea to have it look the same in any browser.

Comment: Yes. I prefer pure css too, but in some cases you just have to use what you have!

Comment: Also by using image mapping you eliminate all browser compatability issues

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code. I think this is what you are looking for. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p7vxzLjq/18/)

```
body {
  background: #21C256; /* green windows theme */
  /* using transparency the tabbar should automatically adjust itself to whatever color is defined here */
}
.tab-bar {
  height: 23px; /* tab height */
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  user-select: none; /* disable text selection */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none; /* disable image drag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
}
.tab {
  background: #FFFFFF; /* inactive tab background color */
  opacity: 0.726; /* inactive tab transparency */
  width: 213px; /* tab width */
  //max-width: 213px; /* messes up the trapezoid angles */
  margin-left: 0px; /* tab overlap */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /*padding-bottom: 1px;*/

  border-radius: 3px; /* tab curves */
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg); /* tab shape angle */
  box-shadow: 0 0 2pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* tab outline */

  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 8px; /* icon left side margin */
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: -2;  /* inactive tabs are generally in the background */
}
.tab:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 4px 9px 0px 0px;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg); /* untransform tab content (this makes stuff blurry! :( ) */
  -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -khtml-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}
.tab-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.tab-text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
    width: 76%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; /* tab text font */
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision; /* tab text improve rendering */
  font-size: 12px; /* tab text size */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000, 200px, transparent); /* make text fade at the right edge (webkit only)*/
}
.tab-close {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  right: 5px;
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/YlimbFeb56qF.png);
}
.tab-close:hover {
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/rNqZRYHpNQBr.png);
}
.active-tab {
  z-index: -1; /* active tab is in front of other tabs, but still behind the content box */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #F8F9F9); /* active tab color */
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.active-tab:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 25px; /* new-tab-button width */
  height: 14px; /* new-tab-button height */
  margin-top: 5px; /* to vertically center the new-tab-button */
  margin-left: 7px; /* margin between tabs and new-tab-button */
  box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* new-tab-button outline */
  background: #FFFFFF; /* new-tab-button color */
  opacity: 0.626; /* new-tab-button transparency */
  border-radius: 2px; /* new-tab-button curves */
  transform: skew(20deg); /* new-tab-button shape angle */
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -khtml-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
}
.new-tab:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#content {
  z-index: 1; /* the content box is always in the foreground */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F8F9F8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Looks nice in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE10 and below. Also, the base shape (angles) of the tabs should not change when their width is changed.

Comment: ohh....!! for Internet explorer you need to change the logic..try to use display table. I will update the code in a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that the tabs overlap properly, you have to get remove the transparency. My solution also includes various other improvements:

[image: Chrome-like tabs improved]

```css
body {
  background: #21C256; /* green windows theme */
  /* using transparency the tabbar should automatically adjust itself to whatever color is defined here */
}
.tab-bar {
  height: 25px; /* tab height */
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none; /* disable text selection */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none; /* disable image drag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 7px;
}
.tab {
  background: #BAF1CB; /* inactive tab background color */
  opacity: 1; /* inactive tab transparency */
  width: 213px; /* tab width */
  margin-left: 0px; /* tab overlap */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1px 0;
  
  border-radius: 3px; /* tab curves */
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg); /* tab shape angle */
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px -2px black, -2px -1px 2px -2px black; /* tab outline */
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 8px; /* icon left side margin */
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: -2;  /* inactive tabs are generally in the background */
}
.tab:hover {
  background-color: #D0F5DB;
}
.tab-content {
  padding: 2px 0;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg); /* untransform tab content (this makes stuff blurry! :( ) */
  -o-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
  -khtml-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-20deg);
}
.tab-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.tab-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; /* tab text font */
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision; /* tab text improve rendering */
  font-size: 12px; /* tab text size */
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000, 200px, transparent); /* make text fade at the right edge (webkit only)*/
  max-width: 170px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tab-close {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 3px 5px 0 0;
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/YlimbFeb56qF.png);
}
.tab-close:hover {
  background: url(http://250kb.de/u/160430/p/rNqZRYHpNQBr.png);
}
.active-tab {
  z-index: 1000000; /* active tab is in front of other tabs, but still behind the content box */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #F8F9F9); /* active tab color */
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.active-tab:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 25px; /* new-tab-button width */
  height: 14px; /* new-tab-button height */
  margin-top: 5px; /* to vertically center the new-tab-button */
  margin-left: 7px; /* margin between tabs and new-tab-button */
  box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); /* new-tab-button outline */
  background: #FFFFFF; /* new-tab-button color */
  opacity: 0.65; /* new-tab-button transparency */
  border-radius: 2px; /* new-tab-button curves */
  transform: skew(20deg); /* new-tab-button shape angle */
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -khtml-transform: skew(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
}
.new-tab:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; /* the content box is always in the foreground */
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F8F9F8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-bar">

  <li class="tab">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Move the close-Button to the beginning -->
      <span class="tab-close"></span>
      <img class="tab-icon" src="http://amazon.com/favicon.ico"/>
      <span class="tab-text">Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="tab active-tab">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <span class="tab-close"></span>
      <img class="tab-icon" src="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
      <span class="tab-text">Google</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="new-tab"></li>
  
</ul>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Tried it in IE11, IE10 and Firefox. The hover events didn't work at all. :/

Comment: They didn't work in the fiddle by the author as well. I didn't change them.